# Android Status Bar Notifications - Opening the correct activity when selecting a notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I have been having a problem with a notification not opening/going to the correct activity when it has been clicked.

My notification code (located in a class which extends Service):

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();

    CharSequence contentTitle = "Notification";

    CharSequence contentText = "New Notification";

    final Notification notifyDetails =
        new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Consider yourself notified", System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent intent =
          PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
          notifyIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);

    ((NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

If I click the notification while the application which created the service is open, the notification disappears (due to the FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL) but the activity does not switch.

If I click the notification from the home screen, the notification disappears and my app is brought to the front, however it remains on the activity which was open before going to the home screen, instead of going to the main screen.

What am I doing wrong? How do I specify the activity that will be pulled up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

May have actually answered my own question:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notifyIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, would you please mention what the "Main.class" contains ?

Comment: And what is getApplicationContext()  ?

Comment: Main.class would be the activity that you want to open/goto.

and getApplicationContext is a method in the Activity class that is inherited from the ContextWrapper class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29